# Apache TikaParser throws uncatchable exceptions

Tags: java, exception, apache-tika

i'm currently trying to develop a tool which uses Apache TikaParser to extract the content from different files. In most cases everything works fine but there a some files where Tika throws the following exception:

```
Mar 09, 2020 11:21:58 AM org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat <init>
WARNING: Invalid format: "_([$€-2]\ * "-"_);"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported [] format block '[' in '_([$€-2]\ * "-"_)' with c2: null
        at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.formatType(CellFormatPart.java:373)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.getCellFormatType(CellFormatPart.java:287)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.<init>(CellFormatPart.java:191)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat.<init>(CellFormat.java:193)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat.getInstance(CellFormat.java:167)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.getFormat(DataFormatter.java:343)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatRawCellContents(DataFormatter.java:901)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatRawCellContents(DataFormatter.java:873)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.FormatTrackingHSSFListener.formatNumberDateCell(FormatTrackingHSSFListener.java:143)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ExcelExtractor$TikaHSSFListener$TikaFormatTrackingHSSFListener.formatNumberDateCell(ExcelExtractor.java:673)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ExcelExtractor$TikaHSSFListener.internalProcessRecord(ExcelExtractor.java:447)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ExcelExtractor$TikaHSSFListener.processRecord(ExcelExtractor.java:340)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.FormatTrackingHSSFListener.processRecord(FormatTrackingHSSFListener.java:92)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ExcelExtractor$TikaHSSFListener$TikaFormatTrackingHSSFListener.processRecord(ExcelExtractor.java:666)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.HSSFRequest.processRecord(HSSFRequest.java:109)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.HSSFEventFactory.genericProcessEvents(HSSFEventFactory.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.HSSFEventFactory.processEvents(HSSFEventFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ExcelExtractor$TikaHSSFListener.processFile(ExcelExtractor.java:316)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ExcelExtractor.parse(ExcelExtractor.java:169)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:183)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:131)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.ParserDecorator.parse(ParserDecorator.java:188)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
        at attproc.processors.AttachmentProcessor.run(AttachmentProcessor.java:68)
        at attproc.Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:89)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm trying to catch this exception with the following code:

```
 try {
                        byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                        try {
                            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                            BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
                            ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
                            parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, tikaConfig.pdfConfig);

                            try {
                                tikaConfig.autoDetectParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content), handler, metadata, parseContext);
                                text = Optional.ofNullable(handler.toString()).orElse("");
                            } catch (Exception ignored) {}

                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
```

"tikaConfig" is a singleton object:

```
public class TikaConfiguration {
    private final TikaConfig tikaConfig;
    public final PDFParserConfig pdfConfig;
    public final Parser autoDetectParser;

    private static TikaConfiguration instance;

    private TikaConfiguration() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("tikaconfig.xml");
        this.tikaConfig = new TikaConfig(stream);
        this.pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
        pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(false);

        tikaConfig.getDetector();
        autoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser(tikaConfig);
    }

    public static TikaConfiguration setConfiguration() {
        if (TikaConfiguration.instance == null) {
            try {
                TikaConfiguration.instance = new TikaConfiguration();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }

        return TikaConfiguration.instance;
    }
}
```

What do i have to do to catch this exception?

Comment: A sanity-check: You have an error thrown when reading an Excel file (the "Apache POI" SS stack trace); and you have a parser that refers (at least, by name) to a PDF config object (`PDFParserConfig()`). Is that deliberate? I would have expected the process to already have separate handlers for Excel  files vs. PDF files. I may be missing something basic, but that looks odd.

Comment: I'm setting the PDFConfig explicitly because i'm enabling OCR for each PDF-document separately. But even without this specific config Tika always throws an exception when i file is somehow broken or borked.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1947) somewhat old thread. What you are seeing looks very similar. It suggests that the POI library, used by Tika for parsing Excel, is throwing a warning, not an error (and your log output reflects that also). The warning happens to include a stack trace in its logging (caught by POI I assume, then passed on to Tika).

The warning would therefore not be caught by your code (it's not a thrown exception).

As one commenter mentions in the JIRA:

> I'm not sure this is even a bug. This is the output of the POILogger, not, e.g. printStackTrace().

Regardless of its status as a bug, a work-around is also proposed in the JIRA: When running the application, redirect the err stream to null (an example is provided).

I downloaded the spreadsheet attached to the JIRA and I was able to recreate their version of your message:

```
WARNING: Invalid format: "_([$Ç-2]\ * #,##0.00_);"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported [] format block '[' in '_([$Ç-2]\ * #,##0.00_)' with c2: null
    at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.formatType(CellFormatPart.java:373)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.getCellFormatType(CellFormatPart.java:287)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.<init>(CellFormatPart.java:191)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat.<init>(CellFormat.java:193)
...
```

However, my program completed successfully. It went on to generate its output correctly.

Comment: After some tries and errors, i've found a solution: I'm completely disabling logging by using the line "LogManager.getLogManager().reset();" in my main-method.